# Python Compile multiple Excels in one with password

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Current python code not copying data over from multiple excels to one master excel, no errors?? Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

Sheets name Sheet1

Also need to incorporate password entry which I think I have done.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

cwd = os.path.abspath(r'C:/Users/eldri/OneDrive/Desktop/test/')
cwd = cwd.replace("'\'", "'/'")
files = os.listdir(cwd)
shtname = ('Sheet1')
print (cwd)
print (files)

xltot = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:  
    if file.endswith('*.xlsx'):
        excel_file.security.workbookPassword = 'password'
        excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(file)
        sheets = excel_file.shtname
        for sheet in sheets: 
            xl = excel_file.parse(shtname)
            xltot = xltot.append(xl)
xltot.to_excel('compiled_xl.xlsx', 'Compiled Excels')
print("Done")

print shows:

    C:\Users\eldri\OneDrive\Desktop\test
    ['cgnbcgnn.xlsx', 'cgncgn.xlsx', 'cgncgnc.xlsx', 'cgng.xlsx', 'fdgfg.xlsx', 'gcncgn.xlsx', 'gcngn.xlsx', 'nfvn.xlsx']
```

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: whats the error message? from a quick glance your calling a method on `excel_file` but the object hasn't been initialised.

Comment: Hey @Manakin I am not getting any error message? all I get is what is printed above. that is what's confusing me. what about excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(file) do I need to swap with excel_file.security.workbookPassword = 'password'.                                      

If i take away the * in if file.endswith('*.xlsx'): I get FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cgnbcgnn.xlsx'

Comment: I assume `excel_file` has already been defined and you've omitted it from the code otherwise there would be an error. For password you'll need to use `openpyxl` or `xlwings`

Comment: @Manakin wouldn't excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(file) give excel_file a variable so wouldn't need to be defined, the pd.ExcelFile is a built in function with panda? also already importing openpyxl do you know how I would incorporate this? currently have excel_file.security.workbookPassword = 'password'